# How to run test sequentially with Maven surefire

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

After searching everywhere on internet I post my question here for an possible answer. First of all, sorry for my bad English, I'm a French speaker.

I'm trying to run Java tests in my Jenkins for a continuous integration project. But Maven run the tests in parallel. The First 10 tests need to be runned sequentially because they initialize database and some templates.

I found this link on the official page : https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html
but when I use `@NotThreadSafe` on my Java test class as they said I got an error :

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> could not parse error message:   symbol:   class NotThreadSafe

I use Maven 2.2.1, Junit 4.6

Do you know how could I do please ?

Edit : my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/P99ReleaseTestSuite.java</include>
            </includes>
            <!--
                <excludes> <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude> </excludes>
            -->
            <skipExec>${surefire.tests.execution.skip}</skipExec>
            <testFailureIgnore>${surefire.tests.execution.ignore-error}</testFailureIgnore>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I run these tests in a linux server. On windows, in my eclipse, all tests run sequentially

Comment: First this means you don't have unit tests you have integration tests which you should not run with JUnit cause there is no defined order of execution (better use TestNG which can define such order) nor is maven-surefire-plugin the correct way (maven-failsafe-plugin). Furthermore You need to turn off in maven-surefire-plugin running tests in parallel (I can't remember the options cause you are using such an old Junit version). Apart from that please use Maven 3+ cause [Maven 2 is end of life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use Maven 3 because, I'm working on a software that have more than 10 years old. On this project, Maven, Junit, Java are old, and everyday is a battle for me. However, in my eclipse I'm able to run theses tests without problems. How is it possible ?

Comment: You can use Maven 3 cause Maven 3 can use JDK 1.3 to compile and run tests for the code...but you have to separate the run time of maven and your code (keyword: toolchains). If you run the tests in Eclipse you are not running with the JDK which you have started Eclipse with apart from that you are using a different compiler in eclipse...Furthermore I would have already upgraded this old project a long time ago...